# Apache Camel: Unable to get the Exception Body

Tags: apache-camel, esb, jbossfuse

Whenever there is normal flow in my Camel Routes I am able to get the body in the next component. But whenever there is an exception(Http 401 or 500) I am unable to get the exception body. I just get a java exception in my server logs.
I have also tried onException().. Using that the flow goes into it on error, but still I do not get the error response body that was sent by the web service(which I get when using POSTMAN directly), I only get the request in the body that I had sent to the web service.

Also adding the route:

```java
from("direct:contractUpdateAds")
        .to("log:inside_direct:contractUpdateAds_route_CompleteLog?level=INFO&showAll=true&multiline=true")
        .streamCaching()
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
        .log("before calling ADS for ContractUpdate:\nBody:${body}")
        .to("{{AdsContractUpdateEndpoint}}")
        .log("after calling ADS for ContractUpdate:\nBody:${body}")
        .convertBodyTo(String.class)
        .end();
```

Comment: You should mention which component you use to make the HTTP call (`camel-http`, `camel-http4`, `camel-jetty`...).

Comment: I was using camel-http

Comment: Can you provide the code for the whole flow? Also, how are you trying to fetch the exception body?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Option 1: handle failure status codes yourself**

The [throwExceptionOnFailure=false endpoint option](http://camel.apache.org/http.html#HTTP-HttpEndpointOptions) (available at least for `camel-http` and `camel-http4` endpoints) is probably what you want. With this option, `camel-http` will no longer consider an HTTP Status >= 300 as an error, and will let you decide what to do - including processing the response body however you see fit.

Something along those lines should work :

```java
from("...")
.to("http://{{hostName}}?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
.choice()
    .when(header(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE).isLessThan(300))
        // HTTP status < 300
        .to("...")
    .otherwise()
        // HTTP status >= 300 : would throw an exception if we had "throwExceptionOnFailure=true"
        .log("Error response: ${body}")
        .to("...");
```

This is an interesting approach if you want to have special handling for certains status codes for example. Note that the logic can be reused in several routes by using `direct` endpoints, just like any other piece of Camel route logic.

**Option 2 : Access the `HttpOperationFailedException` in the onException**

If you want to keep the default error handling, but you want to access the response body in the exception handling code for some reason, you just need to access the `responseBody` property on the `HttpOperationFailedException`.

Here's an example:

```java
onException(HttpOperationFailedException.class)
.process(new Processor() {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        // e won't be null because we only catch HttpOperationFailedException;
        // otherwise, we'd need to check for null.
        final HttpOperationFailedException e =
                exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, HttpOperationFailedException.class);
        // Do something with the responseBody
        final String responseBody = e.getResponseBody();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Cyaegha it works. Is there any other way to actually get the error response body on the .onException().  Because otherwise I need to separately apply this condition on each calls..

Comment: I thought it wasn't possible, but looking at the code, I now notice that the `HttpOperationFailedException` has a `responseBody` property, which gets populated with (obviously) the response body... I'm going to edit my answer.